# Android Icon animation to change color

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` defined like this:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_check_simple"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_check_simple"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

where the `ic_check_simple` drawable is one of the material icons with color `#757575`. I pretend that the color of the icon, after the user presses the `ViewGroup` where the `ImageView` is, change to `#00ff00`.

I'm trying to achieve this with the following code:

```java
int colorFrom = R.color.grey_600;
int colorTo = R.color.electric_green;
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
colorAnimation.setDuration(250); // milliseconds
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

  @Override
  public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
    mActivitySelectorIcon.setColorFilter((int) animator.getAnimatedValue(), PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);
  }
});
colorAnimation.start();
```

I believe I've tried all the PorterDuff modes but with no success.

I want this to work in devices running Lollipop and pre Lollipop (minSDK 16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your are animating the resource ids, not the actual colors. so you must do something like this:

```
int colorFrom = GetResources().GetColor(R.color.grey_600);
int colorTo = GetResources().GetColor(R.color.electric_green);
...
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved. Just had to do that and change to `PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP` to achieve what I was aiming.

Comment: ```PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN``` worked better for me. Maybe because one of the colors was semi-transparent

Comment: Thank you very much for the question and this answer! Additional info: used this to better understand the PorterDuff.Mode -> https://medium.com/@tamanna.mohanty.cse14/alpha-composting-using-android-porterduff-8f4a5e8b7932